# Query a view via nested subqueries

Tags: postgresql

Hi have a `v_message` view that looks like this

```
SELECT 
message.id AS "id",
body AS "body",
message.created_at AS "createdAt",
from_phone_number AS "fromPhoneNumber",
to_phone_number AS "toPhoneNumber",
is_read AS "isRead",
json_build_object(
  'id', agent.id,
  'firstName', agent.first_name,
  'lastName', agent.last_name,
  'avatarLink', agent.avatar_link
) AS "createdByAgent",
json_build_object(
  'id', client.id,
  'firstName', client.first_name,
  'displayName', client.display_name
) AS "createdByClient"
FROM message 
LEFT JOIN agent
ON message.created_by_agent_id = agent.id
LEFt JOIN client
ON message.created_by_client_id = client.id
```

I now would like to apply a `WHERE` query like so

```
SELECT * FROM v_message WHERE  v_message."createdByClient".id = 1
```

However I'm presented with the following error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "createdByClient"
```

Comment: If you want to use an index on `created_by_client_id`, do not put the column values in a JSON object. Allow writing a query that directly puts conditions on the column. Why are you using JSON at all?

Answer (score 1):

The operator [`->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) must be used to obtain the element `id` as text/varchar.

Since the returned result is text, we must use `::integer` to convert it to an integer before comparing it to an `integer`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM v_message 
WHERE  ("createdByClient" ->> 'id')::integer = 1
```

OR convert `1` to varchar :

```
SELECT * 
FROM v_message 
WHERE  "createdByClient" ->> 'id' = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation! Could you please elaborate why the returned result is in text when the id is in fact an integer (serial) on the client table

Comment: According to the documentation the `->>` return always value of type text whatever the type of the value in JSON

Answer (score 0):

Elements of a JSON object aren't accessed with dot notation. Instead of `v_message."createdByClient".id = 1`, the proper syntax is `(v_message."createdByClient" -> 'id')::integer = 1`.

Comment: When I try this I get: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the type mismatch.